# Why React returns empty when calling a function for the first time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I enter the first character in the input element  I get "empty string".

```
function form(props) {
    // function getData(e){
    //     e.preventDefault()
    //     console.log(e.target[1].value)
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("")

    function getTitle(e){
        setTitle(e.target.value)
        console.log(title) //First time shows "empty string"
    }

    
    return (
        <form >
            <div>
                <label >Title</label>
                <input type="text"  name="title" onChange={getTitle} />
            </div>
    </form>)
```

The way I see it, I enter a character in the input element, "onChange" event is fired, the function getTitle is run, its sets the "title" variable, which is hooked to the useState hook, and next I console the result. Following this reasoning I expect to get the first character entered. Instead I get "empty string". From the second character onwards the console prints the characters.

With "onInput" function happens the same.

How to solve this and why happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting state is asynchronous, so your `console.log` is running before the state is set.  If you use a `useEffect` hook to view the state, you should see the value.  The `useEffect` hook runs post-render, so you will see your updated state information at that time.

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(title);
}, [title]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTitle` asyncronous, you must check `title` changes in `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(title);
}, [title])
```